# Fix the abnormal line break because of the font size in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=472" name="viewport">
<style type="text/css">
img {max-width:100%;} div { margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}p{margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;word-wrap:break-word;}table{border-collapse: collapse;}td{word-wrap:break-word;font-family:Arial;vertical-align:top;}
</style>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.bumpedFont16 { font-size:1.6em; }.bumpedFont20 { font-size:2.0em; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:472;background-color:#FFFFFF; position:relative; overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word;min-height:830px; padding-left:20;padding-right:20;padding-top:20;padding-bottom:20;">
<style type="text/css">
.s0 {font-size: 17;font-family: Courier;color: rgb(0,0,255);}
.s1 {font-size: 17;font-family: Courier;color: rgb(163,21,21);}
.s2 {direction:ltr;text-align: left;}
</style>
<p class="s2">
<span class="s0">
<span class="bumpedFont16">Testing.</span>
</span>
<span class="s1">
<span class="bumpedFont16">This is a Testing well.</span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how the HTML code look like:
[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

How can I write a generic javascript / css to avoid the text wrap to two lines? Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)** property with `nowrap` value:

> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text
>   wrapping) within text.

for your paragraph:

```
p.s2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Also, instead of multiple internal `<style>` CSS, I'd suggest you to use external CSS instead.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tDvLb/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing abnormal with the line break; it is normal wrapping. It is caused by your setting a fixed width for an element and having content there that does not fit in the element without wrapping, with your CSS settings.

So you need to decide whether you remove or increase the width setting, reduce the font size, or maybe force the content remain on the same line (e.g. the way @Felix suggests) even though this means that it overflows the element.